# Webservice issue in cq5 - [A WebService annotation is not present on class]

Tags: web-services, maven, soap, wsdl, aem

I was working on SOAP JAX-WS with CQ5. I was trying the example available on link "_http://cqblog.inside-solutions.ch/2013/11/01/consuming-soap-web-service-with-jax-ws-in-cq5-6-1/". I used the command "wsimport -keep -verbose http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl" to generate the stubs. When i am calling this below line in my WebServiceClient class, i am getting error as "A WebService annotation is not present on class: com.mercer.jaxws.TempConvertSoap". TempConvertSoap is a proxy class.

*line :-
return super.getPort(new QName("_http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/", "TempConvertSoap"), TempConvertSoap.class);

i am adding the below dependencies to resolve the required jars in maven pom.xml :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Please provide pointers on the same.

Thanks,
Kiran Parab